# How to do a circular background scrolling on android?

Tags: android, listview, background

I am doing a listview with cards. The idea is to put a background that when the user moves the listview items, it rotate as an infiniti image. I mean, there is just one image and when the user scrolling the images is just repeating and repeating.

Let me show you the idea:

Here you can see how the background is repeating while the user scrolling the listview

[image]

And here is the background

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting.  Please post the code you have so I can see what you are working with.  I'd like to work on a solution.

Comment: Hi @krislarson. Actually, I don't have any code. This is just an idea I would want to implement. The problem is that I don't know where to start. I didn't find something similar on the web yet.

I know how to implement a LISTVIEW, how to assign a background, How to animate it. But about how to make the perpetual background rotation no idea. Simple way is to use maybe a viewpager for the background, but I think it is a bad practice. Imagine a listview over a viewpager, I think there have to be another way. Perhaps touching the pixels on the bitmap, IDK.

Comment: I'm having no success with trying to make a custom background for `ListView`.  My next step is to try `RecyclerView`.  Have you found anything?